# rewrite the sql in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, mssql-jdbc

I am in the process of rewriting a query from old MQ SQL project with snowflake sql. I have trouble for the three subquery results from the outer APPLY. Since the MS SQL only return first row of the query. I have tried using snowflake Lateral with  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER(), the LATERAL works in sequence.

Original MS SQL query:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN c.[Committee Date] is not NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 end [C_DATE]
, CASE WHEN r1.[roster] = 1 THEN 1
    ELSE CASE WHEN coalesce(r2.[R-NID],0) = 1 AND coalesce(r3.[R-TID],0) = 0 THEN 2 
    ELSE CASE WHEN coalesce(r2.[R-NID],0) = 0 AND coalesce(r3.[R-TID],0) = 1 THEN 3 
    ELSE CASE WHEN coalesce(r2.[R-NID],0) = 1 AND coalesce(r3.[R-TID],0) = 1 THEN 4 
    ELSE 10
    END END END END [Roster_IND]
FROM Stage os
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 1 [roster]
        FROM [Master_R] m
        where m.[N_ID] = s.N_ID
        AND m.[T_ID] = s.T_ID
        )r1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 1 [R-NID]
        FROM [Master_R] m
        where m.[N_ID] = s.N_ID
        AND m.[T_ID] <> s.T_ID
        )r2
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 1 [R-TID]
        FROM [Master_R] m
        where m.[N_ID] <> s.N_ID
        AND m.[T_ID] = s.T_ID
        )r3
OUTER APPLY (select TOP 1 [Committee Date]
            FROM C_SOURCE r
            WHERE r.N_ID = s.N_ID
            )c 
WHERE s.load_date = '2023-07-17';
```

The rewrite snowflake:

```
with MR_CTR  as (
  SELECT T_ID ,N_ID
  FROM Master_R 
  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY T_ID, N_ID ORDER BY N_ID) = 1
)
select 
 CASE WHEN r1.N_ID is not NULL and r1.T_ID is not NULL THEN 1
 ELSE CASE WHEN r2.N_ID is not null and r3.T_ID is NULL then 2
 ELSE CASE WHEN r2.N_ID is null and r3.T_ID is NOT NULL then 3
 ELSE CASE WHEN r2.N_ID is not null and r3.T_ID is NOT NULL then 4
ELSE 10
END END END END OPS_Roster  
FROM Roster_Stage as s,
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
 select * 
 from MR_CTR r
 where r.N_ID  = s.N_ID and 
 r.T_ID = s.T_ID ) as r1 
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
 select *  
 from MR_CTR r 
 where r.N_ID  = s.N_ID and 
r.T_ID <> s.T_ID ) as r2 
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  select *  
  from MR_CTR r 
  where r.N_ID  <> s.N_ID and 
  r.T_ID = s.T_ID ) as r3
LEFT JOIN (
  select TOP 1 Committee_Date 
  FROM C_SOURCE r 
  WHERE r.N_ID = s.N_ID) c 
WHERE s.load_date = '2023-07-17';
```

I have tried using snowflake Lateral with  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER(), the LATERAL works in sequence.

The rewrite snowflake:

```
with MR_CTR  as (
SELECT T_ID ,N_ID
        FROM Master_R 
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T_ID, N_ID ORDER BY N_ID) = 1
)
select
CASE WHEN r1.N_ID is not NULL and r1.T_ID is not NULL THEN 1
    ELSE CASE WHEN r2.N_ID is not null and r3.T_ID is NULL then 2
    ELSE CASE WHEN r2.N_ID is null and r3.T_ID is NOT NULL then 3
    ELSE CASE WHEN r2.N_ID is not null and r3.T_ID is NOT NULL then 4
    ELSE 10
    END END END END OPS_Roster
FROM Roster_Stage as s,
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (select * from  MR_CTR  r where r.N_ID  = s.N_ID and r.T_ID = s.T_ID ) as r1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (select *  from MR_CTR r where r.N_ID  = s.N_ID and r.T_ID <> s.T_ID ) as r2
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (select *  from MR_CTR r where r.N_ID  <> s.N_ID and r.T_ID = s.T_ID ) as r3
LEFT JOIN (select TOP 1 Committee_Date FROM C_SOURCE r WHERE r.N_ID = s.N_ID)c 
WHERE s.load_date = '2023-07-17';
```

Answer (score 1):

not the main point, but lets rewrite the CASE to be just one level. CASE statements WHEN clauses are evaluated in the order of the rules presented, so you can just many WHEN clauses, and it keeps falling through:

```
CASE 
    WHEN r1.N_ID is not NULL and r1.T_ID is not NULL THEN 1
    ELSE CASE 
        WHEN r2.N_ID is not null and r3.T_ID is NULL then 2
        ELSE CASE 
            WHEN r2.N_ID is null and r3.T_ID is NOT NULL then 3
            ELSE CASE 
                WHEN r2.N_ID is not null and r3.T_ID is NOT NULL then 4
                ELSE 10
            END 
        END
    END
END as OPS_Roster
```

so now this can be written:

```
CASE 
    WHEN r1.N_ID is not NULL and r1.T_ID is not NULL THEN 1
    WHEN r2.N_ID is not null and r3.T_ID is NULL then 2
    WHEN r2.N_ID is null and r3.T_ID is NOT NULL then 3
    WHEN r2.N_ID is not null and r3.T_ID is NOT NULL then 4
    ELSE 10
END as OPS_Roster
```

much more relaxed..

so if I simplify the SQL to get the JOIN's feeling right, and to test with:

```
WITH Roster_Stage(N_ID, T_ID) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 10), -- exact
        (2, 20), -- other T_ID
        (3, 30), -- other N_ID
        (4, 42), -- others for BOTH
        (5, 50)  -- no match
), Master_R(N_ID, T_ID) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 10),
        (1, 10),    
        (2, 21),
        (2, 22),     
        (101, 30), 
        (102, 30),
        (4,43),
        (103,42)
), C_SOURCE(N_ID, Committee_Date) as (
    select * from values
        (1, '2023-07-18'::date), 
        (1, '2023-07-17'::date), 
        (2, '2023-07-16'::date), 
        (3, '2023-07-15'::date),
        (4, '2023-07-14'::date)
), MR_CTR AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT T_ID ,N_ID
    FROM Master_R 
)
select *
FROM Roster_Stage as s
LEFT JOIN MR_CTR as r1 
    ON r1.N_ID = s.N_ID and r1.T_ID = s.T_ID
LEFT JOIN MR_CTR as r2
    ON r2.N_ID = s.N_ID and r2.T_ID <> s.T_ID
LEFT JOIN MR_CTR as r3
    ON r3.N_ID <> s.N_ID and r3.T_ID = s.T_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    select 
        N_ID, 
        ANY_VALUE(Committee_Date) as Committee_Date
    FROM C_SOURCE
    GROUP BY 1
) as c
    ON c.n_id = s.n_id
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

This gives the rows I would expect:

| N_ID | T_ID | T_ID_2 | N_ID_2 | T_ID_3 | N_ID_3 | T_ID_4 | N_ID_4 | N_ID_5 | COMMITTEE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | 1 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2023-07-18 |
| 2 | 20 |  |  | 21 | 2 |  |  | 2 | 2023-07-16 |
| 2 | 20 |  |  | 22 | 2 |  |  | 2 | 2023-07-16 |
| 3 | 30 |  |  |  |  | 30 | 102 | 3 | 2023-07-15 |
| 3 | 30 |  |  |  |  | 30 | 101 | 3 | 2023-07-15 |
| 4 | 42 |  |  | 43 | 4 | 42 | 103 | 4 | 2023-07-14 |
| 5 | 50 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

we can now put a COUNT on the Rn values get the same as the SELECT 1 from the original SQL:

```
select 
    s.*
    ,count(r1.n_id) as c1
    ,count(r2.n_id) as c2
    ,count(r3.n_id) as c3
    ,c.Committee_Date
FROM Roster_Stage as s
LEFT JOIN MR_CTR as r1 
    ON r1.N_ID = s.N_ID and r1.T_ID = s.T_ID
LEFT JOIN MR_CTR as r2
    ON r2.N_ID = s.N_ID and r2.T_ID <> s.T_ID
LEFT JOIN MR_CTR as r3
    ON r3.N_ID <> s.N_ID and r3.T_ID = s.T_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    select 
        N_ID, 
        ANY_VALUE(Committee_Date) as Committee_Date
    FROM C_SOURCE
    GROUP BY 1
) as c
    ON c.n_id = s.n_id
GROUP BY ALL
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

giving:

| N_ID | T_ID | C1 | C2 | C3 | COMMITTEE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2023-07-18 |
| 2 | 20 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2023-07-16 |
| 3 | 30 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2023-07-15 |
| 4 | 42 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2023-07-14 |
| 5 | 50 | 0 | 0 | 0 | null |

moving the counting to a CTE for easy reading, and plugging the CASE statement from earlier back in we get:

```
WITH Roster_Stage(N_ID, T_ID) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 10), -- exact
        (2, 20), -- other T_ID
        (3, 30), -- other N_ID
        (4, 42), -- others for BOTH
        (5, 50)  -- no match
), Master_R(N_ID, T_ID) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 10),
        (1, 10),    
        (2, 21),
        (2, 22),     
        (101, 30), 
        (102, 30),
        (4,43),
        (103,42)
), C_SOURCE(N_ID, Committee_Date) as (
    select * from values
        (1, '2023-07-18'::date), 
        (1, '2023-07-17'::date), 
        (2, '2023-07-16'::date), 
        (3, '2023-07-15'::date),
        (4, '2023-07-14'::date)
), MR_CTR AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT T_ID ,N_ID
    FROM Master_R 
), counting_done as (
    select 
        s.*
        ,count(r1.n_id) as c1
        ,count(r2.n_id) as c2
        ,count(r3.n_id) as c3
        ,c.Committee_Date
    FROM Roster_Stage as s
    LEFT JOIN MR_CTR as r1 
        ON r1.N_ID = s.N_ID and r1.T_ID = s.T_ID
    LEFT JOIN MR_CTR as r2
        ON r2.N_ID = s.N_ID and r2.T_ID <> s.T_ID
    LEFT JOIN MR_CTR as r3
        ON r3.N_ID <> s.N_ID and r3.T_ID = s.T_ID
    LEFT JOIN (
        select 
            N_ID, 
            ANY_VALUE(Committee_Date) as Committee_Date
        FROM C_SOURCE
        GROUP BY 1
    ) as c
        ON c.n_id = s.n_id
    GROUP BY ALL
    ORDER BY 1,2
)
select 
    n_id
    ,t_id
    ,Committee_Date
    ,CASE 
        WHEN c1 > 0 THEN 1
        WHEN c2 > 0 and c3 = 0 then 2
        WHEN c2 = 0 and c3 > 0 then 3
        WHEN c2 > 0 and c3 > 0 then 4
        ELSE 10
    END as OPS_Roster
FROM counting_done 
ORDER BY 1,2
;
```

with:

| N_ID | T_ID | COMMITTEE_DATE | OPS_ROSTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2023-07-18 | 1 |
| 2 | 20 | 2023-07-16 | 2 |
| 3 | 30 | 2023-07-15 | 3 |
| 4 | 42 | 2023-07-14 | 4 |
| 5 | 50 | null | 10 |

Now of note, the DATE is using a ANY_VALUE because the original `TOP 1` has no sort order, so you where getting a effectively random value, so I have made that explicit, but I assume you really want something like MAX or MIN

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It is really helpful. I will follow your suggestion and rewrite the snowflake queries.